# Unable to install Anaconda on macOS Monterey. Stuck at 'running package scripts'

Tags: installation, anaconda, macos-monterey

As the title says I'm trying to install anaconda onto my MacBook running macOS Monterey. I feel like I have tried everything. Have booted in safe mode, have downloaded older versions, have even set my profile picture to default (it was somehow a fix for another piece of software with the same install error). It simply won't get past the last little bit of 'running package scripts'. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was stuck too, in reality it was just slow. The last step install window said install would take less than a minute but it took a while to install it, 4+GB. Checking

`ls ~/anaconda3`

I saw that new files, folders were adding so something was happening and eventually it did install.

Comment: Same for me. Took 10 min on a 2021 Macbook Pro M1, but eventually finished fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the first link below, `csoja` gave a clue to solve this issue following the instructions in the second link.

1. https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12940
2. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#the-installation-failed-message-when-running-a-pkg-installer-on-osx

In my case, I successfully installed the Anaconda distribution for M1 `Anaconda3-2022.05-MacOSX-arm64.pkg` after changing the owner of my shell config files from `root` to my current user name `cgironda`.

[image: Before installation]

[image: After installation]

I hope this would be helpful!.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue and the way I fixed it was by going into Finder and searching for a folder named 'Anaconda3'. Not entirely sure why but I when I completely deleted this folder from my machine and tried to install again everything seemed to work just fine. Hope this works for you!

PS: On the successful install it did still get stuck on again for like 10 mins